# sandbox.useFakeTimers use cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, datetime, sinon

`sinon.useFakeTimers()` can stub global Date constructor `new Date()`

Which purposes and use cases has `sandbox.useFakeTimers` ?

From documentation

> Fakes timers and binds the clock object to the sandbox such that it too is restored when calling sandbox.restore(). Access through sandbox.clock

it still unclear how to use the second method.

`new Date()` in `SUT` still returns original time-stamp

Answer (score 2):

The idea is not to replace Date; it is to avoid waiting on setTimout as it says in the docs:

> Fake timers is a synchronous implementation of setTimeout and friends
>   that Sinon.JS can overwrite the global functions with to allow you to
>   more easily test code using them

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');

var executed = false;

function doSomething() {
    setInterval(function() {
        executed = true;
    }, 10000);
}

describe('doSomething', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.clock = sinon.restore();
  });

  it('should execute without waiting on the timeout', function(){
    doSomething();
    this.clock.tick(10001);
    assert.equal(executed, true);
  });

});
```

In this example, the function doSomething will execute after 10000 milliseconds. Instead of waiting on that to assert the test, one could simulate time passing by using this.clock.tick(10001) and then assert that the test is passing.